# Spring-retry @Recover method works only in interface definition

Tags: java, spring, spring-retry

I'm using `spring-retry` to provide retry policy for my business logic. I have Interface and the service that implements it

```
public interface MyInterface {
    @Retryable(maxAttempts = 5, backoff = @Backoff(value = 0L))
    void doSth() throws Exception;

    @Recover
    void recoverIfFailed(Exception e);
}

@Service
public class MyService implements MyInterface {
    public void doSth() throws Exception {
            throw new Exception();
    }

    public void recoverIfFailed(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Recovered!");
    }
}
```

and in this configuration everything working fine. However I cannot understand why I mustn't move `@Recovery` annotation to the interface implementation like this:

```
@Service
public class MyService implements MyInterface {
    @Retryable(maxAttempts = 5, backoff = @Backoff(value = 0L)) // -- this is working
    public void doSth() throws Exception {
            throw new Exception();
    }

    @Recover // -- this is not working!
    public void recoverIfFailed(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Recovered!");
    }
}
```

I really would like to not expose my recovery method in the interface (as it seems to be my internal logic) but I cannot due to this issue. Can anyone advise what can be an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted an [open pull request to fix this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/pull/124).

As a work-around, use `@EnableRetry(proxyTargetClass = true)`.

Comment: Is this issue fixed or in-progress yet?

Comment: The pull request is still open; I suggest you make a comment over there.